# Ruby On Rails: How to write yml configurations in a file when deploying with Capistrano 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, capistrano3

My problem is really simple but I just can't find an answer on google.

I would like to insert a yml configuration into a remote file on my server through a Capistrano task.

While it was really easy with Capistrano 2 and the "put" command, I just can't find the right way to do it with Capistrano 3.

For instance, here is my yml configuration:

```
    set(:database_username, "db_user")

    ask(:database_password, "Database Password: ")

    db_config = <<-EOF
      base: &base
        adapter: postgresql
        encoding: unicode
        reconnect: false
        pool: 10
        username: #{fetch(:database_username)}
        password: #{fetch(:database_password)}

      staging:
        database: #{fetch(:application)}_staging
        <<: *base

      production:
        database: #{fetch(:application)}_production
        <<: *base
    EOF
```

I'd like to insert my "db_config" variable in the database.yml file. Using Capistrano 2 I would do so like this:

```
put db_config, "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
```

But with Capistrano 3 it no longer works. 
I tried something like this:

```
execute "echo '#{db_config}' > #{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
```

But end of lines are not kept, they are replaced by ";" because of the 'echo' command.

Does anyone have ever performed something like this with Capistrano 3?

Otherwise, I will just go along with a "database.yml.example" and modify it directly after deployment.

Thanks!

[UPDATE] here is my whole Capistrano 3 task code:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Create database yaml in shared path"
  task :configure do
    on roles(:db) do
      if capture("cat #{shared_path}/config/database.yml").length > 0
        puts "### INFO: Database.yml already exists"
      else
        set(:database_username, "db_user")    
        ask(:database_password, "Database Password: ")

        db_config = <<-EOF
          base: &base
            adapter: postgresql
            encoding: unicode
            reconnect: false
            pool: 10
            username: #{fetch(:database_username)}
            password: #{fetch(:database_password)}

          staging:
            database: #{fetch(:application)}_staging
            <<: *base

          production:
            database: #{fetch(:application)}_production
            <<: *base
        EOF

        execute "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
        execute "touch #{shared_path}/config/database.yml"

        # Everything works so far. This is the buggy part:
        #execute "echo '#{db_config}' > #{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
        execute "cat '#{db_config}' > #{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had trouble with this solution, because capistrano 3 replaces newlines with semicolons. So here is my code:

```
namespace :setup do
  task :setup_database do
    ask(:db_user, 'db_user')
    ask(:db_pass, 'db_pass')
    ask(:db_name, 'db_name')
    db_config = <<-EOF
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: #{fetch(:db_name)}
  username: #{fetch(:db_user)}
  password: #{fetch(:db_pass)}
    EOF

    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
      upload! StringIO.new(db_config), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It seems to be a really good solution. I don't have time to test it yet though... But as soon as I'll test it, I will come back here. Thanks! :)

Comment: It's been a while since I went here... Actually I am now using Ansible to deploy my config files and prepare the needed stuff by capistrano before using capistrano. The couple "ansible" + "capistrano" works in a beautiful way. I'm accepting this answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
execute "cat '#{db_config}' > #{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
```

Comment: Nop... I already tried that and had the error: SSHKit::Command::Failed: cat /project/shared/config/database.yml stdout: Nothing written
cat /project/shared/config/database.yml stderr: Nothing written

Comment: You mean, for db_config? This is a variable created within the capistrano task. And if I replace cat by echo it does work but each end of line are replaced by ";". (and I just replaced my normal path by /project... I don't think there is something wrong with the path as if I test cat by copy/pasting the whole path on my server, it works). I'll edit my question with the whole Capistrano task.

Comment: You can do this by adding the Environment Variables for the Data you want to replace in Remote Server. Do the same for the Development machine too. And then use the Environment variables. Only the Environment variable names must be consistent.

Comment: This is a rather good solution you are proposing dharin. But I wonder: is there any way to write in file on remote server using Capistrano 3? I just find it hard to beleive that such a tool does not include a maybe really simple function to write in a file remotely... This is so weird... Do you think there is a way to 'execute' ruby code remotely? If there is, then perhaps it should be possible by using the 'File' ruby class, shouldn't it?